# Azure Blob File is accesible without authentication

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am using Azure Blob Storage in order to store files (mostly images) for my . NET application.
In one part of the application, the user can attach an image to a report and save it. That will save the file and it will be under a url of the following form :

```
"https://{storageAccountName}.blob.core.windows.net/.../{exportPath}";
```

Afterwards, if the resulting url would be shared by the user, it could be used by anyone (without any authorization taking place) in order to download that image.

I would want to ensure that the files are accessible only within authorized users.

What should I do for such direct access links to externally stored resources where I can't calculate access authorization, so that my files won't be available to anyone with the azure blob link ?

I was reading up on documentation provided by Microsoft regarding Azure Blobs, mostly SAS ( so that I can make my files accessible only to authorized users)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/sas-service-create?tabs=dotnet
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-user-delegation-sas-create-dotnet,   but I haven't figured out yet if that's the way . ( also quick expiration token)

Comment: Not sure I understand what your question is. Can you please edit your question and elaborate more?

Comment: @GauravMantri I've edited. Short explanation : I'm uploading files to azure blob storage. If you have the link to the file, you can access it without authorization. I don't want that to happen( I want it to be accessible for authorized users) and I'm looking for a solution ( SAS/ quick expiry token)

Comment: As an addition: blob containers are private by default, which means any files in it are private, too. If your files are accessible, this means you explicitly set the container to be publicly available. You might be looking for creating a private container and storing files there using either a Managed Identity, the correct connection string or a SAS. (be advised, there are some interesting search terms in there )